# Task process 2010 vs 2013

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have created a workflow that contains a step that starts an approval task process with users A, B, and C present in GROUP Z.

If I use the task process in SharePoint 2013 workflow, after assigning the task to GROUP Z, the system re-assign the **same** task to all users in that group, i.e.,  users A, B, and C;

If I use the approval process in SharePoint 2010 workflow, after assigning the task to GROUP Z, the system creates only ONE individual task, assigned to GROUP Z;

The problem is, in SharePoint 2010 workflow, the system will only take in consideration the FIRST vote from any user (A, B, or C) and then finishes the task, since there is only one individual task which was opened. In SharePoint 2013 workflow, all participants are required to vote in order to complete the task (that is what I need).

I must use the SharePoint 2010 workflow in order to use the “Request Change” function.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're developing your workflow in SharePoint Designer:

- Right-click the task process activity in your SharePoint Designer
  workflow and click Properties
- Set the `ExpandedGroups` property to Yes

If you look at the description of the `ExpandedGroups` property, it says "If true then assign a task to a group means one task will be assigned to each member of the group."